# 'HttpClientFactory' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpclient

I'm writing an application in C#. It pulls the data from Cloudant NoSQL DB.

But when I'm trying to create the Http client:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new LoggingHandler());
```

the compiler throws error saying that

> 'HttpClientFactory' does not exist in the current context

I have also included:

```
using System.Net.Http;"
```

at the top.

I still cannot find where the error is.

Could someone please throw some light.

Comment: Did you reference `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET 5 and I cannot find any dll as System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll. What to do? Please help.

Comment: This library is a part of Web API 2, see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientfactory%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). Do you have web api 2?

Comment: You can install web api 2 with nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi/

Comment: Thanks...But now, I get another error:

Comment: The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3 in project WebApplication6 does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0

Any idea what needs to be done?

Comment: Well... I fixed it...Removed the DNX Core 5 from project.json and everything else fell in place.
Thanks @Andrei for your overwhelming support. You saved my day.

Answer (score 18):

Install the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client/) nuget package.

VS -> Tools -> Nugetpackagemanager -> Package manager console

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

or (specific version)

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 5.2.2

Answer (score 0):

FYI I had the same error and fixed it by adding a new reference:

```
System.Net.Http.Formatting
```

Comment: This fixes the HttpClientFactory issue but usually your using other libraries that are brought over from installing the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client nuget package also.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The reason was that I was trying to install the most up to date version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client nuget package targeting netcoreapp1.1 version of my project, and these are incompatible (if you try to install the nuget package through the Package Manager Console it'll display you the error). I solved it upgrading my project to .NET Core 2. For more info on how to migrate from .NET Core 1.x to 2 follow this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the follow nuget package: Microsoft.Extensions.Http

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Http
```

Comment: WARNING! It is Microsoft.Extensions.Http :)

Comment: Tk's @Edza Edited